# Spring Boot running as maven plugin works, but fails as packaged application

Tags: java, jersey, spring-boot

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot app that uses Jersey. When running with 'mvn spring-boot:run' it starts up and works fine.

However, when I run as a packaged application ('java -jar ...') I get a FileNotFoundException that looks like:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.../appsensor-ws-rest-server-boot/target/appsensor-ws-rest-server-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/lib/appsensor-ws-rest-server-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (No such file or directory)
```

When I look at the generated jar via

```
jar -tf target/appsensor-ws-rest-server-boot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep ws-rest-server
```

, I get:

```
lib/appsensor-ws-rest-server-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So the file appears to be there. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Actually found an answer after a bit more looking, and leaving this for others who might have the same problem.

This resource had the right answer: http://midgetontoes.com/blog/2015/04/13/filenotfoundexception-when-using-jersey-with-spring-boot

Essentially, you have to modify the configuration of the spring-boot-maven-plugin in some cases and add the requiresUnpack element for any dependent jars that require unpacking.